# tabs checkbox AdminLTE v2.3.8 ayuda urgente

Tags: html5, bootstrap

Disculpen tenia este codigo en una plantilla anterior y me pidieron que lo migrara a esta version de *AdminLTE* pero no me funciona y tengo los jefes encima.

Necesito usar checkbox con tabs ayuda por favor

quiero que me muestre el formulario que le corresponde que esta dentro de un tabs cuando le de click a un checkbox.

si presiono el checkbox personaFisica me muestre el formulario de persona fisica.

```
<script>
$('input[name="tabs"]').click(function () {
    $(this).tab('show');
});
</script>

<form id="guardar">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input name="tabs" checked type="radio" data-target="#fisica">Persona Física
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input name="tabs" type="radio" data-target="#moral">Persona Moral
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center" >
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input name="tabs" type="radio" data-target="#extranjeroo">Proveedor Extranjero
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="fisica" class="tab-pane active schedule-pane">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Nombre</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[nombre]">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Apellido paterno</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[apellidoPaterno]">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Apellido materno</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[apellidoMaterno]">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>RFC</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" maxlength="13" name="datos[rfc]">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Nombre comercial</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[nombreComercialF]">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Razon Social</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[razon_social]">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Pagina web (descarga de CFDI's)</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[pagina_web]">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="moral" class="tab-pane active schedule-pane">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Nombre</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[nombre]">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Nombre comercial</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[nombre_comercial]">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>RFC</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" maxlength="13" name="datos[rfc]">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Razon Social</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[razon_social]">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Pagina web (descarga de CFDI's)</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[pagina_web]">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Regimen fiscal</label>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="datos[regimen_fiscal]" value="Fisica" checked>
                    Física
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="datos[regimen_fiscal]" value="Moral">
                    Moral
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Tipo</label>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="datos[tipo_proveedor]" value="Productos" checked>
                    Productos
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="datos[tipo_proveedor]" value="Servicios">
                    Servicios
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Tipo de Servicio</label>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="datos[tipo]" value="Nacional" checked>
                    Nacional
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="datos[tipo]" value="Extranjero">
                    Extranjero
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Teléfono</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[telefono]" maxlength="10">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Banco</label>
              <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="datos[banco]">
                <option selected value="">Seleccione</option>
                <?php 
                foreach ($bancos as $banco) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo base64_encode($banco['bancos_id']);?>"><?php echo $banco['bancos_nombre'];?></option>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
              </select> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>No° de cuenta</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[numero_cuenta]">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>CLABE</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[clabe]">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Calle</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[calle]">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>No° Ext</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[numeroExterior]">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>No° Int</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="datos[numeroInterior]">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>CP</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="codigoPostal" class="form-control input-sm" maxlength="6">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-flat btn-sm" onclick="buscarCodigoPostal(this, '<?php echo base64_encode('buscarCodigoPostal');?>', 'codigoPostal', 'datosPrincipales');"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                  </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-6 divAsentamientos">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divDatosCP">
        </div>
    </div>    
  </form>
```

Comment: Carlos, es muy importante que seas lo mas explicito posible para poder ayudarte correctamente. Saludos.

Comment: ya agregue mas informacion